# What is the most performant way to calculate dependencies in an excel file?

Tags: javascript, excel

I am loading an excel file with several sheets. A lot of these cells have formulae depending on cells either in the same sheet, or other sheets.

I am currently loading in the model using `exceljs`, parsing the formulae using `fast-formula-parser`, then iterating over every sheet -> row -> cell to determine dependencies and add them to a JS Map, where keys are the coordinates (`${sheet}-${row}-${column}`) of the cell and values are the object form of this `{ sheet, row, column }`.

I am not happy with the performance of this, so have been exploring possible improvements for several months now. I can accross graphlib (https://github.com/dagrejs/graphlib), which I thought might solve my issues, but I am finding a 3x performance ***descrease*** with this approach!

This is a very broad question, but what is the most performant way to caclulate these dependencies for later use? For understanding of the size of the data in question, an example file has 16292 and 2099216 edges, which is a lot!

Comment: How are you maintaining the map right now?